# Apply layout on existing slides

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I would like to apply the layout to existing slides in ppt. Below coding is creating new sides and applying the layout. Can someone please assist me on this. I dont want to create new slide. I just want to apply layout to existing slides.

```
Set ppt = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
  Set myPres = ppt.Presentations.Open(pptName)

For i = 1 To 10
   Set slds = myPres.Slides
   Set sld = slds.Add(myPres.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutBlank)
   For Each oLayout In myPres.Designs("Office Theme").SlideMaster.CustomLayouts
       If oLayout.Name = "Title and Content" Then
           sld.CustomLayout = oLayout
           Exit For
       End If
   Next
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Set ppt = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
  Set myPres = ppt.Presentations.Open(pptName)

'For i = 1 To 10
'   Set slds = myPres.Slides
'   Set sld = slds.Add(myPres.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutBlank)
For each sld in myPres.Slides
   For Each oLayout In myPres.Designs("Office Theme").SlideMaster.CustomLayouts
       If oLayout.Name = "Title and Content" Then
           sld.CustomLayout = oLayout
           Exit For
       End If
   Next
'Next i
```